# How to pull specific characters out of a string in R?

Tags: r, string, chess, strsplit

I am trying to extract clock times from PGN chess notation. For example if I have the string:

```
"1. e4 {[%clk 0:00:59.5]} 1... b6 {[%clk 0:00:57.4]} 2. Nc3 {[%clk 0:00:59.4]} 2... Bb7 {[%clk 0:00:57.2]}"
```

How do I just get 59.5, 57.4 etc. ?

I am a beginner in R, I tried strsplit() with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using stringr package:

```
library(stringr)
        
t <- "1. e4 {[%clk 0:00:59.5]} 1... b6 {[%clk 0:00:57.4]} 2. Nc3 {[%clk 0:00:59.4]} 2... Bb7 {[%clk 0:00:57.2]}"

result <- str_extract_all(t, "\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d.\\d", simplify = TRUE) %>% gsub("\\d:\\d\\d:", "", .)
    
result
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "59.5" "57.4" "59.4" "57.2"
```

Comment: @r2evans, please refer to the OP's requested output format. :)

Comment: How many chess games do you know of that finish within 59.9 seconds? The expected output in the OP is given the sample string, which only includes the first minute of game play. I think it's safe to infer that the game will go beyond 1 minute. Or ... if the times are time-between-moves (which is also feasible), it is still possible that a move takes more than 1 minute to think about before moving. You're right, though, it is an assumption on my part.

Comment: @r2evans, my code produces results as requested by the OP. Application of this data is beyond the scope of the question. Also these are amounts of time spent per move, not per game.

Comment: My apologies for bothering you.

Comment: @r2evans, it's all good! :) You've been constructive.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the help, but I should've clarified more. These are in fact 1 minute chess games (bullet variation). Therefore each move time is in seconds or sometimes milliseconds. These numbers are the time on the clock for each player after each move. However, this is not too important as I believe you both answered the question substantially.

Comment: That's fair. I can't think that fast and have not heard of "1-minute chess", so I made a leap. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll modify the data so that I can demonstrate extracting "seconds" with hours and minutes.)

We need to first extract the time-strings with something like

```r
st <- "1. e4 {[%clk 0:00:59.5]} 1... b6 {[%clk 0:00:57.4]} 2. Nc3 {[%clk 0:00:59.4]} 2... Bb7 {[%clk 1:02:57.2]}"
st2 <- regmatches(st, gregexpr("(?<=clk )[0-9:.]+", st, perl = TRUE))
st2
# [[1]]
# [1] "0:00:59.5" "0:00:57.4" "0:00:59.4" "1:02:57.2"
```

and then we can use a helper function to convert that to "seconds":

```r
time2num <- function(x) {
  vapply(strsplit(x, ':'), function(y) sum(as.numeric(y) * 60^((length(y)-1):0)),
         numeric(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
time2num(unlist(st2))
# [1]   59.5   57.4   59.4 3777.2

1*3600 + 2*60 + 57.2
# [1] 3777.2
```

As an alternative, I suspect you're also planning to extract the move itself. Here's the code that keeps them together in a frame:

```r
unlist(regmatches(st, gregexpr(r"{\S+\s*\{\[%clk.*?]}", st))) |>
  strcapture(r"{(\S+)\s*\{\[.* ([0-9.:]+)}", x = _, list(move="", time="")) |>
  transform(time_num = time2num(time))
#   move      time time_num
# 1   e4 0:00:59.5     59.5
# 2   b6 0:00:57.4     57.4
# 3  Nc3 0:00:59.4     59.4
# 4  Bb7 1:02:57.2   3777.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try `regmatches` like below

```
> s <- "1. e4 {[%clk 0:00:59.5]} 1... b6 {[%clk 0:00:57.4]} 2. Nc3 {[%clk 0:00:59.4]} 2... Bb7 {[%clk 0:00:57.2]}"

> as.numeric(regmatches(s, gregexpr("(?<=\\d{2}:).*?(?=\\])", s, perl = TRUE))[[1]])
[1] 59.5 57.4 59.4 57.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution in one pipe:

```
tibble(st) %>%
  mutate(st = str_extract_all(st, "[\\d:.]{9}")) %>%
  unnest(st) %>%
  mutate(sec = sapply(strsplit(st, ":"), function(x) sum(c(3600,60,1) * as.numeric(x))))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  st           sec
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 0:00:59.5   59.5
2 0:00:57.4   57.4
3 0:00:59.4   59.4
4 1:02:57.2 3777.
```

Data (thanks to revans):

```
st <- "1. e4 {[%clk 0:00:59.5]} 1... b6 {[%clk 0:00:57.4]} 2. Nc3 {[%clk 0:00:59.4]} 2... Bb7 {[%clk 1:02:57.2]}"
```